# What the difference between clustering methods?

Tags: machine-learning, k-means, unsupervised-learning, self-organizing-maps

I am focusing on a thesis for introducing clustering methods. Chapter 3 includes hierarchical clustering, partitional clustering and density-based clustering. Meanwhile, chapter 4 is mainly on Self-organizing map, such as 2DSOM and GHSOM.

However, I have no idea on the title of chapter 3 and chapter 4. In my opinion, ch3 is traditional clustering methods, while ch4 is neural network clustering methods. What the best title for dividing and concluding their difference?

Comment: Are you saying you are writing your own masters or doctoral thesis on clustering methods, & you are wondering what the best titles for your chapters should be?

Comment: @gung-ReinstateMonica Yes, that's right, but I have some idea, ch3:Typical methods for clustering，ch4: Self-Organizing Map for clustering, but I am not sure if it is okay

Comment: This question is much better suited for your advisor than for well-meaning but less involved internet strangers.

Comment: @AryaMcCarthy I know, but my advisor doesn't have better idea...

Comment: I agree w/ @AryaMcCarthy. If your advisor doesn't have a problem with your candidate titles, then it's probably OK to go with them.